# How to scroll a view above a list view with the list view (Not with header views....)

Tags: android

So to be clear, I can solve this with a header view and trickiness, but I'd rather not.

I'd like to have a set of tabs (which also contains some profile information) above a view pager, which could have multiple pages, where each page has a list view. I'd like when you start scrolling initially, that the above tab / profile view will move with the list view (so if you try scrolling the list view, the area above scrolls up) and once the listview is scrolled down until it is at the first item, that the above view starts to scroll back into view.

This is not solveable with a header view, as far as I can tell, without stuffing this profile / tab view into the header of every list view the view pager holds, and to keep them in sync (which just sounds silly).

I feel there's a way I can make use of onInterceptTouchEvent with a custom layout / scrollview of sorts, any tips on doing this?

Comment: What happens if you scroll the list on the first page until the tabs are off screen, and then swipe sideways?

Comment: Currently going to go about disabling the swipe behavior of the view pager. I've seen this type of thing in other apps before (I believe instagram had it) and is what my current design is supposed to be.

Another option would be to have the tabs stick to the top and only scroll the profile portion above it.

Comment: You'll need to apply some padding (or a headerview) to each list and use an `OnSCrollListener`s on them all to know when and how far to translate the tabs.

Comment: Sure, was trying to figure out a way to not have to go the route of putting a headerview on each list however... that is the current solution I have but seems like there should be a better way by manipulating the view heirarchys touch handling.

Comment: It's not for the touch handling, it's for making the first list item appear below the tabs when the tabs are visible. You actually don't need a header, you can use `paddingTop` on the ListView and `clipToPadding="false"`. I wouldn't do custom touch handling, use the OnScrollListeners instead to control the translation of the tabs.